# Is there a finite subset of $\mathbb Q^3$ such that its closure under cross product is the whole space $\mathbb Q ^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Is there a finite subset of $\mathbb Q^3$ such that its closure under cross product is the whole space $\mathbb Q ^3$? Here, by closure, I mean the set of elements which can be obtained by repeatedly applying the cross product operation to the initial collection of vectors.

Motivation: Just for fun. (Note that the $\mathbb R^3$ version is immediate by a  cardinality argument.)

Comment: That seems a lot like asking if there is a finite subset of $\mathbb Q$ which generates $\mathbb Q$ under the operations of addition, subtraction, and multiplication. I'd guess probably not to both questions. Maybe you can work up some sort of argument using the infinitude of prime numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such subset. Indeed, let $A\subset \mathbb Q^3$ be a finite set and let $\langle A\rangle$ denote its closure under the cross product. Then there exists an integer $n$ such that $nA\subset \mathbb Z^3$. By induction on the number of cross product operations, for every $a\in \langle A\rangle$ there exists $k$ such that $n^ka\in \mathbb Z^3$.

On the other hand, if $p$ is any prime not dividing $n$, then the element $(p^{-1},p^{-1},p^{-1})\in\mathbb Q^3$ will not have integer coefficients after multiplying by any power of $n$.